# How to compare two point in a given angle?

Tags: c

I have two points **A**, **B** and angle **x**. Let say vector **Aa** and **Bb** have angle **x**.

If exist **A'** in vector **Bb** satify **`AA'b = 90 degree`** then

- if **A' = B** then **`Compare(A, B) = 0`**
- else **`Compare(A, B) > 0`**

Else **`Compare(A, B) < 0`**

```
POINT a, b;
float x;        // in radian

int Compare(POINT a, POINT b, float x)
{
}
```

## Example:

In image bellow, exist **A'** in vector **Bb**, but not exist **B'** in vector **Aa'** satify the given condition, so **A** > **B**.

Question: in **`Compare()`** function what code I need to use to get desired value?

[image]

Comment: This basically isn't a programming issue.

Comment: Project A and B on the X-angled axis (orthographic projection) and compare them (easy). You may alos compute the angle in between Aa and AB wich gives you easy comparison (against 90° angle).

Comment: Don't use integer `struct POINT`. Use float `struct POINTF` instead, or you'll likely fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's simple if you know how to use the [Dot Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of two vectors.

```
// Assumed structure:
struct POINTF{
    float x, y;
};

// include math.h for sin() and cos()
int Compare(POINTF a, POINTF b, float x)
{
    POINTF diff = {a.x-b.x, a.y-b.y};
    POINTF base = {cos(x), sin(x)};
    float r = diff.x * base.x + diff.y * base.y;
    if (r == 0.0f) return 0;
    return (r > 0.0f) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Actually you don't need two temporary vectors. The above code is intended to tell you the calculation of the dot product of two vectors. You can simplify the code into

```
int Compare(POINTF a, POINTF b, float x)
{
    float r = (a.x - b.x) * cos(x) + (a.y - b.y) * sin(x);
    return (r == 0.0f) ? 0 : ((r > 0.0f) ? 1 : -1);
}
```

Comment: your answer is right solution my my problem. Thank you alot!